# How to manage files in Openshift v3 (Next Gen)

Tags: openshift

My application (J2EE + mysql) on Openshift V2 generates a number of html files which are accessible to customers (online visitors). Now, I am migrating this application to Openshift V3.

I have checked various resources but have not found the information on how to manage a file system in the Openshift V3 environment, including  creating/accessing/updating from an application and making files accessible via uri.

Comment: To clarify: In Openshift v2, these html files are under ~/app-root/data/my-html-directory/

Comment: In OpenShift V3, you need to make a persistent volume claim to get storage and mount that at a directory in your container. You can then write to that directory.

Comment: Is there any step-by-step instruction on this, including exposing files (.html etc) to public?

Comment: You can start with https://blog.openshift.com/experimenting-with-persistent-volumes/ That uses command line, but principles the same when using the web console.

Comment: As to how to expose files to the public, that depends on the sever stack you are using. That has nothing to do with whether you use persistent volumes